# WLST Python script unable to accept the variable from Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, python, weblogic

I created a WLST Script that checks if a user belongs to a particular group.
The shell script reads input for the user and group name & sends to it to the python script. This is the python script:

```py
d_user=sys.argv[1]
print 'User is ' +d_user
d_group=sys.argv[2]
print 'Group is ' +d_group

connect(userConfigFile='WebLogicConfig.properties',userKeyFile='WebLogicKey.properties',url='t3://wl-test.com:80')

realmName=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm()
authProvider = realmName.getAuthenticationProviders()

from weblogic.management.security.authentication import GroupEditorMBean
print "Checking if 'd_user' is a member of the group 'd_group' ... "
atnr=cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupAuthenticationProvider("DefaultAuthenticator")
if atnr.isMember('d_group','d_user',true) == 0:
  print "+d_user is not member of +d_group"
else:
  print "+d_user is a member of +d_group"
```

This is the output:

```
./UserGroupCheck.sh
Enter the user name you want to check : weblogic
Enter the group name you want to check for weblogic : Administrators
CLASSPATH=...
PATH=...

Your environment has been set.

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

User is weblogic
Group is Administrators
Connecting to t3://wl-test.com:80 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server..
...
Checking if 'd_user' is a member of the group 'd_group' ...
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "UserGroupCheck.py", line 20, in ?
weblogic.management.utils.NotFoundException: [Security:090259]Group d_group can not be found.
        at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
weblogic.management.utils.NotFoundException: weblogic.management.utils.NotFoundException: [Security:090259]Group d_group can not be found.
```

It fails complaining that the **group is not found**. The python script is able to accept the variables for `d_user` and `d_group` initially, however once it is connected to the Weblogic domain, it is unable to recognize the values given for `d_user` & `d_group` and instead takes the variable names as the actual input.

```
Checking if 'd_user' is a member of the group 'd_group'
```

The script works fine, if I replace the `d_user` & `d_group` with actual user & groups.

I am unable to figure out what I overlooked.

Comment: See [ask],  and http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes in

```
atnr.isMember('d_group','d_user',true)
```

are the problem:

```
atnr.isMember(d_group,d_user,true)
```

Comment: Thank you Hauke !
I made the change and it worked. However the print command is not picking the variable. 
  print "d_user is not member of d_group"
else:
  print "d_user is a member of d_group"

This is the output:
Checking if d_user is a member of the group d_group ...
d_user is a member of d_group

Comment: @TonyJose `print d_user + " is not member of " + d_group`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Now I get an understanding of this syntax works.
Hauke - thanks for your help